# structure for Admin and user panel in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

Is this the structure to follow: for creating a structure for user and admin

is anything like this???

```
application -> 
controllers 
    ->manage folder
        ->admin controller files
    ->user controller files

models->
    all model files are created her e in this single folder
views->
    >manage folder
        ->admin views files
    ->user views files
```

Then what about the default controller we set in the config.php? And again in the views folder we used to create subfolders as pages and templates, right?

So please help me to form a structure by clubbing all these points.

Comment: @DivyaPai this is the right structure .. go for it...

Comment: @ripa, Thanks for the comments and suggestions. I will do as said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my projects I create folders named "admin" in controller , model and view folders and put administration code there.

but this practice can leads to application vulnerabilities. "www.exsample.com/admin" can be a very easy target for automated hacking tools. so pickup random hard to guess string and make a redirect using .htaccess or routes.

eg:
"www.exsample.com/Gh567R"

Answer (score 2):

Basically there is no standard structure. If You wish to separate admin panel from user interface - You can do this in Your own way.

**HMVC** will help you to achieve this. For my solution, I use below format:-

```
application -> 
   modules -> 
      module_name
```

under module_name folder I use below:-

```
controllers -> 
  manage -> 
     admin controller file
controllers -> 
  user controller file

models -> model file

views -> 
   manage -> admin views file
views -> 
   user views file
```